# How to send the parse users objectId with the twilio module

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, twilio

I have been trying to get the Object id of the parse user, so that i can send it to the users phone number. The cloud code is done in javascript which i am not familiar with. I believe the problem is with my code. Here is what i have done so far:

```
var twilio = require("twilio");
twilio.initialize("myAccountSid","myAuthToken");

// Create the Cloud Function
Parse.Cloud.define("inviteWithTwilio", function(request, response) {

// getting objectId from Parse
var query = new Parse.Query("objectId");

query.equalTo("username", request.params.number);

query.find({

success: function(httpResponse){

response.success("Code found");
},
error: function(httpResponse){

response.error("Code not found");

}

});

// Use the Twilio Cloud Module to send an SMS 
twilio.sendSMS({
From: "myTwilioPhoneNumber",
To:    request.params.number,
Body: "Start using Parse and Twilio!" + query
}, {
success: function(httpResponse) { response.success("SMS sent!"); },
error: function(httpResponse) { response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong"); }
});
});
```

I need help making this code work. And advice on books i can read to improve my understanding of JavaScript would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was finally able to solve my problem. All i actually needed was `Parse.User.current().id`. Here is the working code:

```
var twilio = require("twilio");
twilio.initialize("myAccountSid","myAuthToken");

// Create the Cloud Function
Parse.Cloud.define("inviteWithTwilio", function(request, response) {
// Use the Twilio Cloud Module to send an SMS


var objectId = Parse.User.current().id ;  

twilio.sendSMS({
From: "myTwilioPhoneNumber",
To: request.params.number,
Body: "Your Apps verification code is "  + objectId
}, {
success: function(httpResponse) { response.success("SMS sent!"); },
error: function(httpResponse) { response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong"); }
});  
});
```